# Find the optimal bills combination to pay for a specific value

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am working on game with payment system with the following requirements:

1- Suppose the money bills in the game are: 10,5,4,3,2,1

2- AI needs to choose the least number of bills needed to cover the exact amount,i.e if the required to pay is 8 and AI has (4,4,3,3,2)...He can choose (4,4) but not (3,3,2)

3- In case AI can't make the exact amount using the bills he has, he should choose the combination such that it gives the amount with the least difference value, i.e. if the required amount to pay is 7 and the AI has the following bills ( 10,5,4,4), he choses (4,4) which gives the player 1 more above the needed amount.

Below is my code

```
//sortedValues is a list containing my bills in descending order
//ChosenCardsToPay is a list for the bills I choose to pay with

public void PreparePayment(int neededAmount)
{

    int remainingAmount = neededAmount;

    int chosenAmount;

    while (remainingAmount > 0) 
    {
        chosenAmount = 0;

        foreach (int moneyValue in sortedValues )           
        {
            if (moneyValue <= remainingAmount) 
            {   chosenCardsToPay.Add (moneyValue); //Add Bill Value to my candidate list
                remainingAmount = remainingAmount - moneyValue;
                chosenAmount = moneyValue;
                break;
            }   
        }
        if (chosenAmount != 0)
            sortedValues.Remove (moneyValue);//Remove Chosen Bill from Initial List
        else //If all bill values are greater than remaining amount, i choose the bill with smallest value and add to the candidate list
        {
            chosenAmount = sortedValues.Last();
            sortedValues.Remove(chosenAmount);
            chosenCardsToPay.Add (chosenAmount);
            remainingAmount = remainingAmount - moneyValue;
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine most of the times, but take this case: Required amount is 4 and AI has (3,2,2) as bills. Using the above algorithm, AI chooses (3,2) where he optimal answer is ( 2,2).

May someone direct me to the right thinking about this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Must *least difference value* be always *positive* or it can be either positive or negative? E.g. `[5, 4, 3]` when `10` should be paid. What's the right answer - `12` (`5 + 4 + 3`) or `9` (`5 + 4`)?

Comment: This problem is np-complete, as it is some form of the subset-sum problem. This means you will need exponential time in general. As your code has no recursions or exponential-time parts, it can't solve the problem in general. Your code is a heuristic / approximation based on the greedy-approach.

Comment: You are using greedy algorithm that is not suitable here. Consider dynamic programming approach for similar problems (subset sum , coin change)

Comment: His greedy-approach is suitable if he wan'ts an approximation, but not if he wants the optimum. DP would be good, but depending on the configuration Mixed-Integer-Programming would be even better. But all these approaches have a limit.

Comment: *Take bill* (and you have a subproblem with less *amount* to pay) or *Leave bill* (and you have a subproblem with fewer *bills* to pay), track the best solution so far (for *pruning*)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko , it should either be exact value or more...so in the example you game, the right answer is choosing all bills .

Comment: And guys i have no clue about np-complete/greedy-approach/dynamic programming :)

Comment: I cant really follow, any help here ?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution I came up with.  The idea is to keep track of "overages" and return immediately when you find an exact match.  If no exact match is found you just sort the overages by how much they are over then by how many bills were required and take the first one.  In order to get the fewest bills on exact matches makes sure that `bills` is sorted in descending order.  Also this will return an empty sequence if there isn't a way to cover the amount with the given set of bills.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> CoverAmount(
    int amount, List<int> bills, HashSet<int> used = null)
{
    if (used == null)
        used = new HashSet<int>();
    if (amount <= 0)
        return Enumerable.Empty<int>();
        
    var overages = new List<Tuple<List<int>, int>>();
    for(int index = 0; index < bills.Count; index++)
    {
        var bill = bills[index];
        if (used.Contains(index))
            continue;
        if (bill > amount)
        {
            overages.Add(Tuple.Create(new List<int> { bill }, bill - amount));
        }
        else if (bill == amount)
        {
            return Enumerable.Repeat(bill, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            used.Add(index);
            var bestSub = CoverAmount(amount - bill, bills, used).ToList();
            used.Remove(index);
            bestSub.Add(bill);
            var sum = bestSub.Sum();
            if (sum == amount)
            {
                return bestSub;
            }

            if (sum > amount)
            {
                overages.Add(Tuple.Create(bestSub, sum - amount));
            }
        }
    }

    return overages
        .OrderBy(t => t.Item2)
        .ThenBy(t => t.Item1.Count)
        .FirstOrDefault()?.Item1 ?? Enumerable.Empty<int>();

    // OR this if you are not using C# 6
    // var bestOverage = overages
    //    .OrderBy(t => t.Item2)
    //    .ThenBy(t => t.Item1.Count)
    //    .FirstOrDefault();
    // return bestOverage == null ? Enumerable.Empty<int>() : bestOverage.Item1;
}
```

The following code

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", CoverAmount(8, new List<int> { 4, 4, 3, 3, 2 })));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", CoverAmount(7, new List<int> { 10, 5, 4, 4 })));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", CoverAmount(4, new List<int> { 3, 2, 2 })));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", CoverAmount(10, new List<int> { 11, 6, 5 })));
```

will produce this output

> 4, 4
>
> 4, 4
>
> 2, 2
>
> 11

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, ill check the code and gimme my feedback, but it seems what i want :)

Comment: I tried to run your code but I got the following error: "error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `.'  " at line ".FirstOrDefault()?.Item1 ?? Enumerable.Empty<int>(); "

Comment: I commented the last line and then I got the following error  " error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<test.Tuple<System.Collections.Generic.List<int>,int>>' to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"  May you guide me on how to solve it?

Comment: Are you using C# 6 (VS 2015)?  If not you will not be able to use the `?.` operator.  Instead you'd need to assign the results of `FirstOrDefault` to a variable then check if it is `null` before either returning `Item1` or the empty sequence.  I've added the line to the answer.

Comment: Thank you it worked now...I am actually using C# under Unity Engine. It's working just fine :)